# How to check number file uploaded reach to limit in component uploader

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, file-uploader

I have created my own fileuploader base on magento component. I want to check file number when it reach to limit

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader',
    'ko'
],
function (
    validator,
    UpLoader,
    ko
) {
    return UpLoader.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'uploader/uploader',
            previewTmpl: 'uploader/preview',
            isMultipleFiles : true,
            inputName: 'image',
            uploaderConfig: {
                dataType: 'json',
                sequentialUploads: true,
                formData: {
                    'form_key': window.FORM_KEY
                }
            },
            links: {
                value: '${ $.parentName }:uploadValue'
            }
        },

        //more functions here
        Parent file have lot functions here


        /**
         * This is my constructor
         * Invokes initialize method of parent class,
         * contains initialization logic
         */
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'reset');
            this._super()
                .setInitialValue()
                ._setClasses()
                .initSwitcher();

            return this;
        },

        /**
         *  Retrieve max number file allow in configuration
         */
        getMaxFileNumber: function() {
            return this.uploaderConfig.maxFileNumber;
        },
    });
});
```

Is there a good way to check and return alert message when user number file uploaded reach to limit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will need, i will post my temporary solution here

```
onFilesChoosed: function () {
    var files = this.value();
    if (files.length >= this.getMaxFileNumber()) {
        alert("Max files exceeded, You can't upload more!");
        return false;
    }
    return this;
},
```